# Object-To-Dictionary, compiler-generated function

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a bit out of the loop with the latest features of the C# compiler, so I have to ask this:

Is there a way to get a compiler-generated member function that iterates over all defined and inherited properties of a class (at compile time, as opposed to at run-time by means of reflection) and returns a *name-value* dictionary?

```
class Foo
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }

    [Microsoft.CSharp._SomethingSomething_ToDictionaryConverter]
    // Compiler-generated function:
    // return new Dictionary<string, object>()
    // {
    //     { nameof(Foo.A), this.A },
    //     { nameof(Foo.B), this.B },
    //     { nameof(Foo.C), this.C },
    //     { nameof(Foo.D), this.D },
    // }
    public Dictionary<string, object> ToDict();
}

// Then,
var foo = new Foo();
var d = foo.ToDict();    // yay!
```

Comment: So you want a reflection-like system without reflection? Lol, that would be nice and a performance killer.

Comment: have you tried to write something for roslyn

Comment: @DanielA.White, you've got a point! I didn't, but that seems a very nice idea :)

Comment: read your code, at compile time? every property will have `default(type)` as those are non-readonly properties... you don't need nothing special to do `default(type)`

Comment: You might be able to do it with a T4 template.

Comment: And what good would this "compile time dictionary" do that a runtime built one doesn't? How are you planning on leveraging the dictionary at compile time? Or are you just interested in not paying the runtime performance price?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desire to remove boilerplate code that is dependent on state that is known in its entirety at compile time is not unique. This is actually what the [`Fody`](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) library was designed to do. It simplifies (relative speaking) the ability to manipulate the final generated IL as part of the build process.

Looking at the list of libraries that are already built, I noticed that the [`ToString` library](https://github.com/Fody/ToString) performs something similar to what you desire. Specifically, it requires consumers to decorate a class with the `[ToString]` attribute, and the "weaver" will iterate over all of the public properties, override the `ToString()` method and get it to emit a custom string. In your example, you would create something like a `[ToDict]` attribute, then create a weaver that would iterate over all of the public properties, define a new `ToDict()` method, and return a dictionary.

Comment: Nice explanation. Not sure it gives the 
 
user1475331  all he wanted but I like it.

Comment: Yeah, he'd need to write his own weaver, which is a non-trivial investment.